# What is the physical interpretation of negative Unruh temperature?

Tags: gravity, temperature, acceleration, unruh-effect

Actually the [Unruh temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect#Temperature_equation) is vectorial since it is proportional to acceleration but derived for only one space dimension so at least positive and negative. What can negative Unruh temperature mean? I suppose negative temperature is the temperature experienced from accelerating away, and positive temperature is experienced when acceleration towards.

Comment: The Unruh temperature is proportional to the magnitude of the acceleration. Sometimes people say it's proportional to the acceleration, without the words "magnitude of," but that's only an abbreviation.

Comment: Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/675904

Answer (score 1):

The Unruh temperature can't be negative and it is not a vectorial quantity. Its value is given by $T_U = \frac{a}{2\pi}$ (in units with $\hbar = c = G = k_B = 1$), where the constant $a$ occurs on the expression of the four-velocity of the accelerated observer, $u^\mu = a \left[x \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^{\mu} + t \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^{\mu}\right]$. It satisfies $a^\mu a_\mu = a^2$, where $a^\mu$ is the four-acceleration of the observer, which is why we call it the acceleration.

Notice that $a < 0$ does not mean the observer is moving in the negative $x$ direction. Instead, it means the observer is moving in the negative $t$ direction, i.e., it is going backwards in time. Hence, regardless of the spatial direction the observer is moving, as long as they are going to the future, the Unruh temperature is positive.

Notice also that all of these comments work perfectly fine in $(3+1)$ dimensions. The observer must have a constant acceleration for them to experience the Unruh effect (this is due to the fact that one needs the four-velocity to be tangent to a timelike Killing field generating a bifurcate Killing horizon). As a consequence, the spatial motion will be one-dimensional, even in a $(3+1)$ dimensional spacetime. We can just choose the coordinate $x$ to point along the direction of motion.

For further details, see, e.g., Wald's [*Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime and Black Hole Thermodynamics*](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/Q/bo3684008.html), Sec. 5.1.